# Typescript use subfield as key for an other object

Tags: typescript

I have an object like this

```
const foo = {
    key1: {
        path: 'hello'
    },
    key2: {
        path: 'world'
    },
    key3: {
        path: 'smile'
    }
};
```

I would like to define a new object with keys depending on `foo` object.
I know I can do

```
const bar: {
    [key in keyof typeof foo]: number
} = {
    key1: 1,
    key2: 2,
    key3: 3
};
```

Can I do it so it use the sub field `path` from `foo` ?

```
const bar: {
    [key in ???]: number
} = {
    hello: 1,
    world: 2,
    smile: 3
};
```

Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do it if you preserve the string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `path` properties, such as using a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on the initializer:

```
const foo = {
  key1: {
    path: 'hello'
  },
  key2: {
    path: 'world'
  },
  key3: {
    path: 'smile'
  }
} as const; // <-- here
```

The way you did it, the types of `path` are all just `string` and the information you need has been lost.  Anyway, once you have that you can use [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to compute the relevant [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of path string literal types:

```
type Foo = typeof foo;
type FooPaths = Foo[keyof Foo]["path"];
// type FooPaths = "hello" | "world" | "smile"
```

And then it's straightforward:

```
const bar: Record<FooPaths, number> = {
  hello: 1,
  world: 2,
  smile: 3
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDeAoGMDWBTATwEYAudLbGABwEMoALMgcnrwBs2QmKBfAGgr4CAJjKZK1OoxhMA7iABObACbds-QYQDMYitloNmEALYBLNnjUweGHjBoQYoSFADcGDFAJU8MAGKIKDBePiBw8IjuIb4BIAAKUo6osQDaQmH+iAC6KQBEBvS5We4A9CXB3jGICQxJMLmsHCC5MAA+9fJKyi3tuSbmeLkYztAwAEY0CmQASnigCsoAPLE19BB8MGAArsZjeAoAfEHiMI2cZEQC2J0qZMJXMP0WZFq2QA)

Comment: That perfectly awnser my question, thanks alot !